# strlen in a function changing output

Tags: c, function, strlen

Okay, I tried to figure it out, but couldn't;

So there is a function in my source code with two arguments passed (9 and 1, as Strings)

```
char * plus( char *a, char *b ){
   char sa[101] = {0};
   char sb[101] = {0};
   static char _s[101] = {0};
   int i;
   int st = 0;
   int sto;
   for( i = strlen( a ) - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
       sa[strlen( a ) - 1 - i] = a[i]; 
   }
   for( i = strlen( b ) - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
       sb[strlen( b ) - 1 - i] = b[i];
   }
   for( i = 0; i < strlen( sa ); i++ ){
       sto = 0;
       if(( sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0' ) > 9 ) sto = 1;
       sa[i] = ( sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0' ) %10 + '0';
       st = sto;
       if( st && sa[i + 1] == 0) sa[i + 1] = '1';
   }
   for( i = strlen( sa ) - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
       _s[strlen( sa ) - 1 - i] = sa[i];
   }
   return _s;
}
```

It should return "10" but instead "*0", but constantly, (so not "undefined behaviour")
What's wrong?

Edit:

if I pass `strlen( a )` instead of `strlen( sa )` in line `for( i = 0; i < strlen( sa ); i++ ){`
then it works correctly

Comment: Why one line `for` and `if` blocks?  This makes it less readable IMO.

Comment: Why `- 1` here `strlen( a ) - 1`?

Comment: The function is for summing two integers which are in a string, like `char *a="2334"`
Which for and if did you mean?

Comment: *... but constantly, (so not "undefined behavior")* Not true.

Comment: Why should it? if i=0 then no probs, and it can't be less then zero, because of the for-state

Comment: You need to show how the function is called. If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you find the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: This way: `char a[100] = "9";
 char b[100] = "1";
 char *result = plus( a, b );
 
 printf( "%s", result );`

Comment: `sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0'` - I'm not sure what you were expecting, but FYI the decimal value of `'0'` is 48; thus, `2 * '0'` is decimal 96, which happens to be the backtick character (`). ???

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica It's for converting ascii in `sa[i]` and `sb[i]` to integer. It's `(sa[i] - '0') + (sb[i] - '0') + st`. Took my a min to get it too ; )

Comment: "undefined behaviour" means anything can happen; "anything" includes always showing some particular result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0'

is negative. Because you do `sa[i + 1] = '1'` then `strlen(sa)` get's incremented in the loop. Because of that, `sb[i]` is equal 0 because it's the zero terminating character on the last run when `i == strlen(sa) == 2`. Then the calculation becomes:

```
sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0' = 
  '1' +     0 +  1 - 2 * '0' = 
   49 +     0 +  1 - 2 * 48  =
                50 - 96      =
                -46
```

Because that's minus 46, sa[i] becomaes:

```
a[i] = ( sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0' ) %10 + '0' =
                                    -46 %10 + '0' =
                                         -6 + '0' =
                                              '*'
```

Most probably in the loop:

```
 for( i = 0; i < strlen( sa ); i++ ){
```

You have to take care what happens when string lengths are not equal. You do `sa[i] = '1'`, but `sb` stays the same. I guess for now you can fix it by replacing

```
  sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0'
```

with something along:

```
  sa[i] - '0' + (sb[i] ? sb[i] - '0' : '0') + st
```

Notes: I do not enjoy your indentation. Please make your code as readable as possible. Use newlines to denote new expressions. Use `{` `}` to denote where you enter loop or if bodies.

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
   for( i = 0; i < strlen( sa ); i++ ){
       sto = 0;
       if(( sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0' ) > 9 ) sto = 1;
       sa[i] = ( sa[i] + sb[i] + st - 2 * '0' ) %10 + '0';
       st = sto;
       if( st && sa[i + 1] == 0) sa[i + 1] = '1';
   }
```

is incorrect because within the loop the array `sa` is being changed. So also the value returned by `strlen( sa )` that is calculated in each iteration is also changed.

When you are using `strlen( a )` instead of  `strlen( sa )` then the array s is not changed in the loop . So the value returned by the expression is fixed.